# R: how to calculate summary for each group and all the data?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I think the following task comes up rather often: calculate summary for each group and over all the data, and display the results in one dataframe. For example, for iris dataframe, we can calculate mean for each column for each Species:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_groups <- iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-Species), mean)

>df_groups
# A tibble: 3 × 5
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
      <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

We can calculate the mean for each column for all the Species, and call the only row as "All Species":

```
df_all <- iris %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-Species), mean) %>% 
    mutate(Species='All Species')

> df_all
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width     Species
1       5.8433      3.0573        3.758      1.1993 All Species
```

Finally, by binding both dataframes we obtain the desired output:

```
df_all %>% bind_rows(df_groups) %>% 
     select(Species, everything()) # make Species the first column

      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1 All Species       5.8433      3.0573        3.758      1.1993
2      setosa       5.0060      3.4280        1.462      0.2460
3  versicolor       5.9360      2.7700        4.260      1.3260
4   virginica       6.5880      2.9740        5.552      2.0260
```

My question is: Can all this be done within one pipeline (without the need to create two dataframes and then binding them)?

Comment: You could do the self-join at the beginning, I suppose: `iris %>% mutate(Species = 'All') %>% bind_rows(iris) %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(mean)`

Comment: @alistaire gosh... that's beautiful and works!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df_all <- iris %>% 
          mutate(Species = 'All Species') %>% 
          bind_rows(iris) %>% 
          group_by(Species) %>% 
          summarise_all(mean)

df_all
```

[image: mean of everything]